# R Get list name when unlisting

Tags: r, list, data.table

I have a big list of character vectors which looks something like this:

```
List of 53095
 $ 30875  : chr [1:10] "<h2 class=\"buildings-page-title buildings- ...
 $ 30876  : chr [1:10] "<h2 class=\"buildings-page-title buildings- ...
```

I want to create my list into a `data.table`, with one column showing all original data (`unlist`ing), and then also add another column that contains original list names (but just the first element not the second element of a list).

*For example:*

```
test<-list("30875"=c("hello", "world", "!"), 
           "30876"=c("Nice","to","meet","you"))

# I could try something like this.

result<-data.table(A=unlist(test), B=names(unlist(test, use.names=T)))
> print(result)
   A      B
1: hello 308751
2: world 308752
3:     ! 308753
4:  Nice 308761
5:    to 308762
6:  meet 308763
7:   you 308764
```

I would want something similar to the above but without the last digits in column `B`, which is the specific element in a list. 
(So, from `[[i]][j]`, I want only the `[[i]]` part.)
Without having to mess with strings in column `B`, after creating something like I did, is there a way to get the desired result from the first place?

**Desired result**

```
   A      B
1: hello 30875
2: world 30875
3:     ! 30875
4:  Nice 30876
5:    to 30876
6:  meet 30876
7:   you 30876
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `rep` along with `lengths` where we repeat the name of the list according to number of elements in it.

```
rep(names(test), lengths(test))
#[1] "30875" "30875" "30875" "30876" "30876" "30876" "30876"
```

To put it in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
data.table(A=unlist(test), B=rep(names(test), lengths(test)))

#      A     B
#1: hello 30875
#2: world 30875
#3:     ! 30875
#4:  Nice 30876
#5:    to 30876
#6:  meet 30876
#7:   you 30876
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is `stack`

```
library(data.table)
setnames(setDT(stack(test)), c('A', 'B'))[]
#      A     B
#1: hello 30875
#2: world 30875
#3:     ! 30875
#4:  Nice 30876
#5:    to 30876
#6:  meet 30876
#7:   you 30876
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
map_df(test, enframe, value = 'A', .id = 'B') %>% 
            select(A, B)
```

Comment: Hi akrun. Thanks for the answer. I have a quick question, Is `setDT` a more prefered way than using `as.data.table()`?

Comment: @wyatt `setDT` should be faster as it converts by reference